# How to say week before last week?

Tags: synonyms

As a data analyst, I am trying to define the time periods in my analysis. I simply compare the weeks with each other.

Let's assume that

- Today is 11.06.2020
- Last week was 01.06.2020 - 07.06.2020

Now, I am looking for a word for the period of **25.05.2020-31.05.2020**

Is there a synonym of "week before last week"?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense :)

Comment: British English "A fortnight ago"

Comment: Your weeks start on Mondays. In the U.S., they would start on Sundays.

Comment: @HotLicks As it is everywhere in the English-speaking world where I've ever been.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think they are looking for a word that refers to the week as a whole - such as "the week before last". "A fortnight ago" would suggest to me a specific time about 14 days prior.

Comment: The problem with these natural phrases is that they're bound to the present. "The week before last" only makes good sense *this week*.  Consult that report a week or two from now and the period names/labels/definitions would be misleading if they used the natural phrases.  "One week earlier" and "Two weeks earlier" would be extensible as "earlier" is not bound to the present as "last" is, but is a relative term. You only need a term for the anchor, the then-current week.

Answer (score 4):

> “The week before last”

is the normal way of saying this, being an abbreviation of “the week before last *week*”. (See [Cambridge online Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/week-month-year-before-last?q=week+before+last).)

It is a standard linguistic construction also used with “day”, “month” and “year”. English does not possess single words to express such temporal terms as in the German: Übermorgen (day after tomorrow) and Vorgestern (day before yesterday).

The [Google book ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=week+before+last&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) indicates the expression is both British and US English usage and has been employed since at least the early 19th century.

Comment: As it uses strange grammar, this fixed expression _is_ an idiom: an extragrammatical idiom.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — All depends on your definition of idiom. I was using the narrow one of "a distinctive expression whose meaning is not determinable from the meanings of the individual words", but Collins admits "a variety of language", which can cover about anything. I don't see how the grammar is strange. Would you say "the week before Christmas" has strange grammar? "last" is just an (obvious) abbreviation for another temporal expression. However, cutting it doesn't alter the answer, so in the spirit of peace and goodwill…

Comment: The week before last is not just BrE.

Comment: @Lambie - Was just playing safe. Will edit.

Comment: Thank you. Somehow my nose goes out of joint re this issue of AmE/BrE. :)

Comment: The term 'idiom' requires a definition suitable to the domain where it is being used. On a site devoted to advanced grammar and semantics, a definition beyond the narrow one you mention is needed. That is the definition of grammatical idioms. See for instance [this Linguistic Society article](https://www.linguisticsociety.org/sites/default/files/e-learning/CxG-lecture2-idioms.pdf) for a more scholarly treatment. / 'The week before last' uses what appears to be a determiner as the prepositional complement. This normally requires another determiner (before the next eruption; after his last book)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — I bow to your superior knowledge. When I started in academic science I suffered from imposter's syndrome. On this site I'm just an imposter.

Answer (score 0):

In reporting, a distinction is sometimes made between 'previous' and 'prior', namely, that the previous, say, week, is just that, but the prior week is the week previous to the previous week, which allows a 3-week comparison of activity: current week, current week minus 1, and current week minus 2.